# if x in list doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build sort of a 1-player-battleship game in python, and when I run the code I have so far in IDLE, it prints out "Error in input" every time no matter what I input, and stays in the while loop. I have no idea what the issue is.
Here is the code:

```
from random import randint

def five_die(): #function 5 sided die
    return str(randint(1,5))

def print_board(board):  #function to print board
    letters = []
    letters.append([" "])
    letters.append(["A"])
    letters.append(["B"])
    letters.append(["C"])
    letters.append(["D"])
    letters.append(["E"])
    for i in letters:
        print(i, end=" ")
    print("\n")
    for i in range(1,31):
        print (board[i-1],end=" ")
        if i % 6== 0:
            print("\n")


visual_board = [] #creating the board
for num in range(30):
    if num % 5 == 0:
        visual_board.append([str(num//5+1)])
    visual_board.append(["O"])


print_board(visual_board) #calling print_board function

actual_board = [] #creating the "actual board"
for num in range(1,6):
    actual_board.append(["A"+str(num)])
    actual_board.append(["B"+str(num)])
    actual_board.append(["C"+str(num)])
    actual_board.append(["D"+str(num)])
    actual_board.append(["E"+str(num)])

column = five_die() #placing ship
row = five_die()
if column=="1":
    column="A"
elif column=="2":
    column="B"
elif column=="3":
    column="C"
elif column=="4":
    column="D"
else:
    column="E"
ship=column+row

breaker = 1 #getting user guess and checking validity
while breaker == 1:
    ship_guess=str(input("\n\nGuess a square (from A1 to E5)!: "))
    ship_guess=ship_guess.upper()
    if ship_guess in actual_board:
        breaker=2
    else:
        print ("Error in input!")
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `ship_guess=str(input("\n\nGuess a square (from A1 to E5)!: "))`
input gives string already in python 2.x

Comment: Simplify, `actual_board = [''.join([i, str(j)]) for i, j in itertools.izip(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], range(1, 6))]`, `['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4', 'E5']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're wrapping each entry in your board lists in a second list, rather than writing a string directly. e.g.

```
letters = []
letters.append([" "])
```

So, try:

```
letters = []
letters.append(" ")
```

... etc.

`"A"` and `["A"]` are not the same thing, so your "in" test won't match.